# how to read the file using python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am reading the above .txt file, in which I have to identify those three letter WORDS like (ARW, CZC, DUN and so on). Later I have to read the test case ids like VR-GREQ.... until the next language. but I have problem in reading this .txt file. 
Below is my code :

```
with open(output_filename) as parser_file:
        for language in parser_file:
            language = language.strip()
            if(re.search('[A-Z]', language)):
                lines = parser_file.readlines()
```

I have to code further, can someone please help me ?

my new code :
    output_filename = r"C:\Usersktop\TEST\Language\Output.txt"
    def writing():

```
    rx = r'^([A-Z]{3})$'

# define a dictionary for the languages
    languages = {}
    # looks for exactly three uppercase letters from beginning to end

    # define a temporary list
    tmp = list()
    for line in open(output_filename, 'r+'):
        m = re.search(rx, line, re.MULTILINE)
        if m is not None:
            if len(tmp) > 0:
                languages[current] = tmp
            tmp = list()
            current = m.group(1) # current holds the actual language tag
        else:
            if len(line) > 0:
                tmp.append(line.strip())

    # after the loop
    if len(tmp) > 0:
        languages[current] = tmp
    print languages
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want done with this data.

Comment: For example - I want to read ARW with all this ids : ARW
VR-GREQ-299684_6j 

VR-GREQ-299684_6k 

VR-GREQ-299606_3 

VR-GREQ-299606_4 

VR-GREQ-299606_5 

VR-GREQ-299606_7 

VR-GREQ-299606_9 

VR-GREQ-299607_4 

VR-GREQ-299608_1 

VR-GREQ-299563_10

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find strings of length 3, then use [A-Z]{3}. You could split the whole list into arrays based on the location of those 3 character "words".

EDIT: answering your comment...

`headers=re.split('[A-Z]{3}\n',YOUR_STRING)` will find the "header" for each section.
Then you can do `NEW_STRING=YOUR_STRING[YOUR_STRING.find(headers[0]):YOUR_STRING.find(headers[1])]`

With loops and other tools, this should help you do what you're aiming for.

Comment: thanks. can you please tell me how to read the ids of the languages. ARW, CZC, DUN and so on are the languages.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of your comments, the question became clearer. Consider the following code:

```
import re

string = your_string_as_above
rx = r'^([A-Z]{3})$'

# define a dictionary for the languages
languages = {}

# define a temporary list
tmp = list()
for line in re.split(r'\n', string):
    m = re.search(rx, line, re.MULTILINE)
    if m is not None:
        if len(tmp) > 0:
            languages[current] = tmp
        tmp = list()
        current = m.group(1) # current holds the actual language tag
    else:
        if len(line) > 0:
            tmp.append(line.strip())

# after the loop
if len(tmp) > 0:
    languages[current] = tmp
print languages

""" prints out a dictionary with the language as key
{'FRC': ['VR-GREQ-299659_18', 'VR-GREQ-299659_19', 'VR-GREQ-299659_28', 'VR-GREQ-299659_31', 'VR-GREQ-299659_32'], 'CZC': ['VR-GREQ-299684_6k', 'VR-GREQ-299606_6', 'VR-GREQ-299606_8', 'VR-GREQ-299640_1', 'VR-GREQ-299640_5', 'VR-GREQ-299640_6', 'VR-GREQ-299640_7'], 'DUN': ['FB_71125_1'], 'ARW': ['VR-GREQ-299684_6j', 'VR-GREQ-299684_6k', 'VR-GREQ-299606_3', 'VR-GREQ-299606_4', 'VR-GREQ-299606_5', 'VR-GREQ-299606_7', 'VR-GREQ-299606_9', 'VR-GREQ-299607_4', 'VR-GREQ-299608_1', 'VR-GREQ-299563_10']}
""""
```

See [a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/lCgmIf).

Comment: getting error as :     lines = parser_file.readlines()
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data

Comment: no !! I want to identify the languages then later I want to read all the ids until the next languages but I am not able to do that. can you please tell me how ?

Comment: it is just printing the letters but i want to read the data of all the respective languages and save that in a variable later I am writing that languages into the respective worksheet of the same .xls

Comment: I understood that. thanks. I want to read the ids of the respective language. how to do that ?

Comment: can you please tell me how to go further ?

Comment: @sam: See my updated answer and the code on ideone.com

Comment: with open(output_filename, 'r+') as parser_file:
        for line in re.split(r'\n', parser_file):  is that right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103763/discussion-between-sam-and-jan).